# Need help extracting data

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I'm a teacher on a $20,000/year salary so I'm using Wolfram Programming Lab online to experiment with Mathematica scripts to save money (although I'm hoping to get a raspberry pi as a birthday present which comes with Mathematica). Problem is, I had it produce a rather large data set. Now the file size is above what can be opened and I can't access anything I've done with the notebook. I know this is a rather unorthodox question, but could someone paste the contents of this file (without any large data sets) here so I can recreate my work. Here's the file:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/Twinprimeplotting%20%281%29.nb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go... I just stripped all the output (using Cell->Delete All Output) and here is the file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b6hzlc63j1rhjg/Twinprimeplotting%20%282%29.nb?dl=0

Comment: Thanks Bill! Was there anything after that long data set? Seems like I had at least a few more cells after as well.